# Excel or SQL Vertical data to Horizontally

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql

I have data extract from SQL Server about 5000 rows as shown below. And I copy-paste it into an Excel file.

[image: SQL Result]

But I want to convert data to this format:

[image: Formatted View]

Should I complete this job at the first step (SQL Server side) or in Excel? Which solution is more easier to investigate and learn?

Also I would be glad if you could give an example.

Thanks.

Comment: Excel side sounds to be more appropriate because it doesn't seem to have any logic other than cut & paste manually.

Comment: not sure if this can help, but may be look into Pivot. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Have you looked at pivoting on the `ID` column before copying to Excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a known or maximum number of columns you can use `PIVOT` in concert with `row_number()`

If the maximum is unknown, you would need Dynamic SQL

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=1dde1018e426dd7a4b45e89d09997669)**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select A.ID
              ,B.* 
         from (Select *
                     ,Grp = row_number() over (partition by ID order by ID) 
                From  YourTable
              ) A
         Cross Apply ( values (concat('Column1-',Grp),Column1)
                             ,(concat('Column2-',Grp),Column2)
                             ,(concat('Column3-',Grp),Column3)
                             ,(concat('Column4-',Grp),Column4)
                     ) B(Col,Val)
       ) src
 Pivot (max(Val) for Col in ( [Column1-1]
                             ,[Column2-1]
                             ,[Column3-1]
                             ,[Column4-1]
                             ,[Column1-2]
                             ,[Column2-2]
                             ,[Column3-2]
                             ,[Column4-2]
                             ,[Column1-3]
                             ,[Column2-3]
                             ,[Column3-3]
                             ,[Column4-3]
                            )  ) pvt
```

**Results**

[image]

**EDIT - Update for Dynamic SQL and Variable Datatype**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = (
Select string_agg(concat('[',Col,N,']'),',') within group (order by N,Col)
 From (values ('Column1-')
             ,('Column2-')
             ,('Column3-')
             ,('Column4-')
      ) A(Col)
Cross Join ( Select distinct N=row_number() over (partition by ID order by ID) From  YourTable ) B
)

Set @SQL = '
Select *
 From  (Select A.ID
              ,B.* 
         from (Select *
                     ,Grp = row_number() over (partition by ID order by ID) 
                From  YourTable
              ) A
         Cross Apply ( Select col = concat([Key],''-'',Grp)
                             ,Val = value
                        From  OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )) 
                     ) B
       ) src
 Pivot (max(Val) for Col in ( '+@SQL+' )  ) pvt '

 Exec(@SQL)
```

Comment: Thanks for the repply. I know column count in each group but don't know max group count. So i need change this pivoting to dynamic N group count and solve the data type problems. Some columns int some datetime etc.

Comment: @Lacrymae Some important details missing from your question.   See update